Building number 3276
This is probably a really obscure one because as far as I remember it is just two shots in the film - the film never returns to the same building or at least the shot is not repeated.
Also, I have no idea what the film was about - this is the only thing I remember about it, so asking the question is a real long shot.
One of the main characters in this film walks across a street towards an office type building with a glass entrance.
Above the glass door of the building, printed on the glass, is the number of the building. The number is 3276 and it is written in a kind of 'curly' typeface.
As the character enters the building the view cuts to a shot from inside the foyer so the view of the door and number are reversed.
Because of the typeface used the building number clearly reads as 'arsE'. No reference is made to this and I don't remember the film being a comedy.
It may have been entirely accidental (I'm not sure how widely that mild profanity is used outside of the UK, so may have been missed by the film makers), or it may have been included as a joke.
I'd love to know what the film was as I have recounted this story a number of times and I'm sure people think I'm making it up.
The only other things I can think of that might narrow things down a bit are:

I believe the film was in colour.
I saw the film at least 20 years
ago on TV in the UK.
The character entering the building was male.
The building the character entered was in what looked like a business
district with possibly/probably high rise buildings.
The location may
have been USA, but not certain.


Have added the only other things I remember.. it was a long long time ago unfortunately - hence my believing even asking is a long shot!

From memory, this sounds like The Bank Job http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0200465/?ref_=nv_sr_1 That was full of subtle humour like that.  But it doesn't match your 20 years ago criterion.

Afraid not, too recent and wasn't Jason Statham. Was definitely more than 15 years ago so anything post 2002 is definitely not it.
